# MVC Message Class events driven

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi All i am new to MVC and trying to make my desktop applicaitons port to Web apps.

So here is my problem - I have a WCF service on every desktop and normally in my fat apps i open up a connection and listen to incoming messages per machine. Then its event driven by the type of message ariving back to the fat app.

So my issue lies in MVC where i would like a persistant class in my controller (not sure correct terminology) where i can hook up events and drive back into my webpage via Signalr?

I would prefer not to rewrite my service, but i am unsure on how to tackle implementing this in MVC - This is my main stumbling block :(

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you using a specific framework? or are you building the MVC yourself?

Comment: No specific framework, Just building it myself

Answer (score 0):

In some MVC frameworks they have another part called 'Components'.  This is where you would store your php files that you would use over the whole framework.  Example is User Identity file to confirm login status.  There you could specify your service and use that over all off your controllers or models depending on your usage.

Comment: Maybe i havent really explained my scenario to well. User 'A' logs into the web app and requests to connect to machine 'x' the web app needs to connect via WCF to the service via a dll and for the example we will call the master connection class 'ConnectionToMachine'. So i would intialise the class and subscribe to various events under it (e.g MachineInformation). I would then request via the ConnectionToMachine to send a message Async and then when the event MachineInformation is fired i would like to display that in the page (E.g SignalR)? How could i possibly implement something like this.